# Limit MYSQL query to 1 result stop failure of fetch_assoc()

Tags: php, mysql

How can I limit my db query to only 1 result so fetch_assoc() doesn't fail. Limit 1 doesn't seem to work, errors I'm getting and php function with sql below.

Warning: mysqli::query(): (21000/1242): Subquery returns more than 1 row in /class.php on line 463

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /class.php on line 465

```
public function getLastTimeStampStatusChanged($column) {

    $sql = "select max(`timeStamp`) from `status` where `".$column."` !=(select `".$column."` from `status` where `timeStamp` = (select max(`timeStamp`) from `status` LIMIT 1))";

    while (!$query) {

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);

        while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {

            $result[] = $row;

        }

    }

    return $result;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you need the LIMIT clause on the query that doesn't have the aggregate in the SELECT list. The minimum fix would be to move a closing paren...

Change this:

```
... from `status` LIMIT 1))
                         ^
```

to this:

```
... from `status`) LIMIT 1)
                 ^
```

---

The longer answer is this may not return the result you want, since that will return just some row, not any determinate row.

Answer (score 0):

Error message gives you everything you need to fix it. Simple your subquery returns more than one row.

First remove `LIMIT 1` from subsubquery (you are using `MAX` so it'll return just one row). Then add that limit to subquery.

```
select `".$column."` from `status` where `timeStamp` = (select max(`timeStamp`) from `status`) LIMIT 1
```

You should also remove `while (!$query)` statement. It doesn't make any sense here.

Answer (score 0):

It should have to be like this

```
public function getLastTimeStampStatusChanged($column) {

    $sql = "select max(`timeStamp`) from `status` where `".$column."` !=(select `".$column."` from `status` where `timeStamp` = (select max(`timeStamp`) from `status` ) LIMIT 1 )";

    while (!$query) {

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

            $result[] = $row;

        }

    }

    return $result;


}
```